# Separate time settings from user locale?

Tags: localization, control-panel, datetime

I would like to render the DateTime fields in the backend with european time format, even though the user I'm logged in with is set to English/US.

[image: DateTime field]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's currently no setting to choose your preferred date and time format. What you can do though, is to hack your craft/app/framework/i18n/data/en_us.php

```php
'dateFormats' => array (
    'full' => 'EEEE, d. MMMM y',
    'long' => 'd. MMMM y',
    'medium' => 'dd.MM.y',
    'short' => 'dd.MM.yy',
),
'timeFormats' => array (
    'full' => 'HH:mm:ss zzzz',
    'long' => 'HH:mm:ss z',
    'medium' => 'HH:mm:ss',
    'short' => 'HH:mm',
),
```